# More than one functions after if then .., don't work in Haskell

Tags: haskell, if-statement, conditional-statements, ghc

I have a basic problem, after if .. then I  can not have more than one function, why?

```
check [] _ _ = []
check (x:xs) limit counter = if (x> head xs && counter < limit)
                              then incr counter -- I want here add another action 
                              else if ( x < head xs )
                                   then check xs limit counter
                                   else  incr x

main = do 
  print $ check [4,3,5,6] 1 0
  --- The answer I aim is : [3,4,5,6]
```

The goal of the check is to find whether each element is bigger than the next one or not, if yes then increase counter and do another action like swap their places, and there is a limit for this action, like here is just 1 time, means just 1 times it can do that action not more.

Comment: Are you wanting to increment the counter and then continue checking the rest of the list?  By the way, you don't modify the value of `counter` or `x` with `incr` (and you should be using `succ` anyway, unless you have `incr` defined somewhere), you're simply returning a new value of the counter.  You have to explicitly call the function again, such as `check xs limit (succ counter)` or `succ x : check xs limit counter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use guards instead:

```
check [] _ _ = []
check (x:xs) limit counter
             | x> head xs && counter < limit = incr counter
             | x < head xs                   = check xs limit counter
             | otherwise                     = incr x
```

You could also use `case` and `MultyIf` extension

Instead `action` from `incr counter` you could write `check xs limit (counter + 1)`

About exchanging, you could try

```
 ...  
| x> head xs && counter < limit = check (head xs : x : tail xs) limit (counter + 1)
```

I see, you also need special case for `head [] = error`, so you should divide you function to `check (x:y:xs) ..` and `check [x]`.

So, for `check (x:y:xs) ..` case we can rewrite

```
 ...  
| x> y && counter < limit = check (y : x : xs) limit (counter + 1)
```

When you do this, you already find that we have empty list as result.
But you want to save modified list

So, try to add  change check function

```
check' xs = reverse . check ([], xs) 0

check ( modXs, []) _ _  = modXs
check ( modXs, [x]) _ _ = x : modXs
check ( modXs, (x:y:xs)) counter limit = ...
```

**Main point**
Inside the function there aren't "static local variables", but in most cases recursion is welcome.
If it is really need to use "static local variables", you could use "data in contents": monads, like `IO`, `IORef` of pure, like `State`

Comment: Thanks @wit but do you know here after incr counter how can I add another function like func1. is it true if I say inr counter >> func1 ?

Comment: @Amir The `incr counter` statement does nothing with it's result, since values are not mutable in Haskell.  Are you wanting to do something with `counter` after it's incremented?

Comment: @bheklilr you are right, I want to use it as it says like a counter.

Comment: @Amir, `modXs` is a variable, where we save modified result list

Comment: @wit , thanks it looks great,  still when I added the other stuff like below get error, could you please just look at that too?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second implementation of `check`:

```
check ( modXs, []) _ _  = modXs
check ( modXs, [x]) _ _ = x : modXs
check ( modXs, (x1:x2:xs)) counter limit 
    | x1 > x2 && counter > limit =  x2:check (x1 : xs)  (incr counter) limit
    | otherwise = x1 : check (x2 : xs) counter limit
```

You're nearly there, but it's ill typed because the first argument to `check` is a pair, while in the recursive definition you provide a list.